# Is it possible to create a (depletion mode) MOSFET using only single type of semiconductor?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, semiconductors, jfet

If I understood [JFET diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFET) correctly, the p-n junction is only used to isolate gate. Using same principle, would it be possible to construct a MOSFET with no junction at all, i. e. a single semiconductor type transistor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is yes a single N or P type depletion mode mosfets can be built.  If you do a search on TFT transistors you will find how they are use in LCD displays.  This is from a my solid state devices text book, which is very old;

[image: TFT single semiconductor type]

Usually depletion mode mosfets are built on a substrate of the opposite type of material.  That is because it is easy to do with current fabrication methods.  The substrate is not needed for the opporation of the device.

Comment: Can you name your devices textbook, btw?

Comment: The textbook is "Solid State Electronic Devices" by Streetman published by Prentice Hall 1972.

Comment: So, to be sure, can a MOSFET (as per the question) be built with no junction at all and is there any having data sheets?

Comment: Yes, a mosfet can be built with no junction at all.  That is what the picture is showing. A semiconductor is deposited on a glass insulator.  One end is the drain.  The other is the source.  A gate insulated from the channel is added to control current flow.  I do know of any devices like this for sale with a datasheet.  I also think that most TFTs used in LCD displays are  probably run in enhancement mode.

Answer (score 0):

> would it be possible to construct a MOSFET with no junction at all, i.
>   e. a single semiconductor type transistor?

[image]

The above is for a P channel JFET as linked in the question.

The gate source region needs to form a depletion layer so that the P channel can be progressively cut-off thus restricting current flow from source to drain. Without the N type material at the gate, a depletion region cannot be formed therefore you cannot control the drain current other than by brute force; taking current away from the source (via the gate) that would otherwise get to the drain.

That's not a transistor any more as far as I see it.

Comment: So, a depletion region wouldn't form without an opposite type semiconductor (by just applying electric field)?

Comment: @valplo you got to ask yourself: why do PN diodes work in forward direction? What would happen if I took away the N, or the P part? You'll find that you'd have built something that doesn't continously allow current to flow. So, no, without the N zone, you can't build any kind of transistor.

Comment: Both P and N material are not needed to create a depletion region.  Take for example the Schottky diode.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_diode

Answer (score 0):

*would it be possible to construct a MOSFET with no junction at all*

No because it is the reverse biased PN junction which provides the isolation needed to turn the device off, meaning no current can flow.

A single bar of N or P type semiconductor in general behaves as a **resistor**. Certain types of on-chip resistors are made this way.